# Impossible MySQL query

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have this tables in my DB:

"USERS"

```
id  email                      name             last_access
1   user1@gmail.com     Name1 Surname1      2012-10-05 13:58:19.0
2   user2@gmail.com     Name2 Surname2      2012-10-05 13:56:59.0
3   user3@gmail.com     Name3 Surname3      2012-10-05 13:57:57.0
```

"NETS_PERMISSIONS"

```
user_id     network_id     perm
1           1234           3
2           1235           3
```

Now, I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.id, user.name, nets.network_id, nets.perm
FROM users as user LEFT OUTER JOIN nets_permissions AS nets
ON user.id = nets.user_id AND nets.perm <> 3 WHERE user.id!=1 AND nets.network_id=1234
```

The result query is empty, but instead I want that
- from the 'nets_permissions' table, are left out rows with perm=3 and user_id and network_id like spiecified in the query (in this case for ex. user_id=1 and network_id=1234): in this case the left part of the query is empty.
- from the 'users' table I want take every row but, if it isn't in the 'nets_permissions' table, the rows have network_id and perm .

So, from this two tables, in this example, I would this result:

```
id    name             network_id    perm
2     Irene Pippo      <null>        <null>
3     Luca Niccolini   <null>        <null>
```

Thank you very much to all of you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you what you want--only users who don't have perm 3 and nework_id 1234

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, n.network_id, n.perm
  FROM users as u 
  LEFT JOIN nets_permissions as n
    ON u.id = n.user_id AND n.perm = 3 AND n.network_id=1234 
 WHERE n.network_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Ok it works! But can you explain to me why! this part of the query `ON u.id = n.user_id AND n.perm = 3 AND n.network_id=1234 
 WHERE n.network_id IS NULL` exactly how works?

Comment: @sharkbait  Even though the database behind the scenes does things  more complex, you can think of it like this: Everything before the WHERE creates a left outer joined table the Users table to the net_permissions.  Run the query without the final where clause and you'll see a list of all users. Ones with  perm = 3 AND network_id=1234  will have that data appended. Adding the where then filters out this table anyone with  perm = 3 AND network_id=1234 leaving only those without that data. FYI: OUTER is the only kind of LEFT JOIN. The OUTER keyword is redundant . LEFT INNER JOIN is nonsense

Comment: Ok Ray! You're been very clearly! Thank you! And what if I would have null value of net_id and perm for users that there aren't in the 'nets_permissions' table, but the rights values of net_id and perm for that users that are in the 'nets_permissions' table? because your solution works very well, but I obtain always net_id and perm of <null> value....

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this (which should work):

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.name, n.network_id, n.perm
FROM users as u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN nets_permissions as n ON u.id = n.user_id 
WHERE (n.perm is NULL || n.perm <> 3) AND u.id <> 1 AND n.network_id = 1234
```

Comment: Is `Not Equal` in MySQL not `!=`?

Comment: Both: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal

Comment: It works, but I think only in this case. There is the possibility that an user has perm=1 but his network_id is 1234. In other words, I want left out the admin of the network (that has perm=3 and his network_id is 1234) but I want include any other user, that could have already a perm(permission) on the net or not.

Comment: Whoops edited now, MySQL doesn't allow that comparison with NULLs.